# Is it possible to set a custom filter on cross filter API in AG-Grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have created an integrated chart using cross filter API offered by Ag-grid. My main purpose of using cross filter API is to filter the grid based on chart interactivity.  Is it possible to set a custom filter on a node click? Currently AG-Grid filters the grid by category on node click by default. But say, I want to set the filterModel such that a number column gets filtered by greater than some value on node click.

Comment: Refer filterOptions `greaterThan` ... link -> https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-provided-simple/#simple-filter-options

Comment: @ShriramJadhav I understand there are filterOptions, but I want to know if we can set a custom filter on the filterModel when a node is clicked in a chart.